# How to convert TLE data into state vectors in ITRF?

Tags: astrodynamics, coordinates

As shown in the question, Now I have a **TLE observation data** and **CPF(Consolidated Prediction Format) data**. According to CPF's documentation, CPF predictions are tabulated satellite state vectors generally in the geocentric Earth-fixed coordinate system of date known as the **ITRF (International Terrestrial Reference Frame)**. 
So what can I do to **convert TLE data into state vectors in ITRF**(Both data at the **same observation time**)?

Here's what I've done so far: 
The observation time is `2022-07-12T11:38:00.043871000`
The TLE data is:

```
0 STARLETTE
1  7646U 75010A   22193.48472273 -.00000146  00000-0 -15590-5 0  9998
2  7646  49.8266  11.4131 0205800   0.2699 359.8273 13.82312865395926
```

The CPF data is(The specific data format can be viewed in [CPF_format](https://edc.dgfi.tum.de/en/oc/cpf/v2/)):
 `10 0 59772  41880.000000  0       -430956.931      -7170514.708            -0.274`
So the **Cartesian coordinate** of the CPF data point at the observation time in **ITRF** is:
 `x = -430956.931, y = -7170514.708, z = -0.274`
Then, I converted **TLE data** into a **state vector** in **ITRF** through the following **python code**:

```
   from tletools import TLE
   from astropy import units as u
   from astropy.coordinates import GCRS, ITRS, CartesianRepresentation
   time = 2022-07-12T11:38:00.043871000
   s = '1  7646U 75010A   22193.48472273 -.00000146  00000-0 -15590-5 0  9998'
   t = '2  7646  49.8266  11.4131 0205800   0.2699 359.8273 13.82312865395926'
   tle = TLE.from_lines('starlette', s, t)
   orbit = tle.to_orbit()
   r, v = orbit.rv()
   gcrs = GCRS(CartesianRepresentation(r[0] * u.m, r[1] * u.m, r[2] * u.m), obstime=time)
   itrs = gcrs.transform_to(ITRS(obstime=time))
   x_ecef = itrs.x.value
   y_ecef = itrs.y.value
   z_ecef = itrs.z.value
```

However, the results are far from the CPF data：
·`x_ecef = -387448.4141639284, y_ecef = -7172405.299520155, z_ecef =  23871.227963843405`
Later, I also considered **precession, nutation, pole shift** and other factors. Due to the large amount of code, here it will not be displayed. But maybe my research is not enough, the difference between CPF and TLE data is still obvious．
So, what efforts should I make to solve the above problems? Can I directly consider precession, nutation, pole shift and other factors in `astropy.coordinates`?
I will appreciate it for any help!

Comment: did you solve your problem? I use sgp4 as the accepted answer suggested, still has a big difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not quite a case of garbage in, garbage out. It's a garbage in the middle problem. Toss the `tletools` package you are using in the circular file (aka the garbage can), which is where it belongs. It's pretty obvious from [the code](https://github.com/FedericoStra/tletools/blob/master/tletools/tle.py), starting at line 209, that `TLE.to_orbit` is doing exactly the wrong thing. It treats the TLE elements as if they were classical osculating elements, which very much is not the case.

[Astropy](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/satellites.html) recommends using the [sgp4](https://pypi.org/project/sgp4/) package.